# Drop empty databases from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a bunch of empty databases showing up in my MongoDB (from time to time, and for an unknown reason) and I'm looking for an easy way to drop all of the empty ones. Here is a piece of the results of the 'show dbs' command, and it's clear which ones are empty and which is not.

```
rs0:PRIMARY> show dbs
1442036273           (empty)
1442643016           (empty)
1443249599           (empty)
<script>document     (empty)
<script>foo<         (empty)
CFIDE                (empty)
CSCOnm               (empty)
CVS                  (empty)
ConsoleHelp          (empty)
ControllerWeb        (empty)
DB4Web               (empty)
MYDB                 0.203GB
HNAP1                (empty)
IDMProv              (empty)
MM                   (empty)
MSWSMTP              (empty)
NASApp               (empty)
Orion                (empty)
OvCgi                (empty)
Reporting            (empty)
SAPHostControl       (empty)
...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did any of the answers below helped you solve the issue?

Comment: yes, I tried chridam's approach and it worked. Harsh Makani seems to have a similar idea but nicely wrapped in a .js file :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **[`listDatabases`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/listDatabases/#dbcmd.listDatabases)** command to get the array of databases which have empty data, iterate over the list and call the **[`dropDatabase`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/dropDatabase/#dbcmd.dropDatabase)** method on the database object. The following demonstrates this

```
> use admin
> var dbs = db.adminCommand("listDatabases").databases
> printjson(dbs)
[
        {
                "name" : "admin",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
                "empty" : false
        },
        {
                "name" : "local",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 83886080,
                "empty" : false
        },
        {
                "name" : "test",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 486539264,
                "empty" : false
        },
        {
                "name" : "test2",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 0,
                "empty" : true
        },
        {
                "name" : "test3",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 0,
                "empty" : true
        }
]
> var emptyDbs = dbs.filter(function(db){ return db.empty; });
> printjson(emptyDbs)
[
        {
                "name" : "test2",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 0,
                "empty" : true
        },
        {
                "name" : "test3",
                "sizeOnDisk" : 0,
                "empty" : true
        }
]

> emptyDbs.forEach(function(e){
    var db = new Mongo().getDB(e.name);
    db.dropDatabase();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a javascript loop that do the job and then execute it in the mongoconsole.

```
var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames()
for(var i in dbs){
    if (db.getCollectionNames() != null) {
       continue;
    }
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( dbs[i] );
    print( "dropping db " + db.getName() );
    db.dropDatabase();
}
```

save it to dropemptydbs.js and then execute:

```
mongo dropemptydbs.js
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no easy way to delete the empty db's.

You can use the following steps in the mongo shell

- Use db name
- db.dropDatabase()